# How do you get custom dimensions from Google Analytics reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics

The new 2.0 mobile API no longer supports custom variables, and states that you need to use custom dimensions.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/migration?hl=en

That is all fine and good, but there is no [obvious or documented](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) way to get those custom dimensions out of the core reporting API 3.0.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

We have users that are mobile and web and we need to get all of our data out no matter what device. How can we get CUSTOM DIMENSIONS out through there?

http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has added support for this.

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/07/40-new-data-points-in-google-analytics.html

Answer (score 3):

just request "**dimension1**" or similar name. You can get it in code examples in admin section / **custom defenitions**.